# Iterating list within tuple

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, tuples

With this:

```
a = [(string,[(string,integer)])]
```

I want to do

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i][1])):
        var = a[i][1][1] # get the integer value
```

but without loops (functional programming).

Could someone give me a hand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: loops, sorry. fixed.

Comment: Depends what `# stuff` is.

Comment: `len(a)` is an integer (not iterable). `for`-loops require iterables. You probably meant `for i in range(len(a))` ... `a[i]` which is written more idiomatically in Python as `for e in a` ... `e`

Comment: iterate and do what?

Comment: Thanks, user4122880, you're right

Comment: `[x[1][0][-1]for x in a]` would get all the ints in a list of tuples like your input, you do not need two loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this worked:

```
def main(lst):
    if lst == []
        return
    aux(lst[0][1])
    return main(lst[1:])

def aux(lst):
    if lst == []
        return
    x = lst[0][0] # I actually wanted the string, so I could get an index in another list,
                  # but lst[0][1] gives the int
    # stuff I wanted to do #
    return aux(lst[1:])
```

Thanks anyway to all that replied.

Answer (score 1):

I supose you want to do something like this:

```
def ListIterator(somelist):
    if len(somelist) == 0:
        return
    elif somelist[0] == isinstance(somelist,list):
        ListIterator(somelist[0])
    else:
        #dostuff
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, even if I couldn't use this as a solution, wouldn't it be `elif isinstance(somelist[0],list):` ?